# Django: retrieving ManyToManyField objects with minimum set of queries

Tags: django

My code looks like this:

`models.py`

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=42)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='post')
    #...various fields...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, null=True)
```

`views.py`

```
posts = Post.objects.all().values('id', 'user', 'title')
tags_dict = {}
for post in posts: # Iteration? Why?
    p = Post.objects.get(pk=[post['id']])  # one extra query? Why?
    tags_dict[post['id']] = p.tags.all()
```

How am I supposed to create a dictionary with tags for each Post object with minimum set of queries? Is it possible to avoid iterating, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will need a loop. But you can save one extra query in each iteration, you don't need to get `post` object to get all its tags. You can directly query on `Tag` model to get tags related to post id:

```
for post in posts:
    tags_dict[post['id']] = Tag.objects.filter(post__id=post['id'])
```

Or use Dict Comprehension for efficiency:

```
tags_dict = {post['id']: Tag.objects.filter(post__id=post['id']) for post in posts}
```

Comment: thanks, that is great. It works like a charm! Please, when you find time change `Tags` to `Tag`. :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have renamed it to `Tag`. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Django version >= 1.4 and don't really need a dictionary, but need to cut down the count of queries, you can use [this method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) like this:

```
posts = Post.objects.all().only('id', 'user', 'title').prefetch_related('tags')
```

It seems to execute only 2 queries (one for `Post` and another for `Tag` with INNER JOIN).

And then you can access `post.tags.all` without extra queries, because tags was already prefetched.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
        {{ tag.name }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```